# .Net 8 Blazor URL rewriting, routing with param at the beginning of the string., Is it possible?

Tags: routes, blazor

I have a problem, I have an older asp.net webforms app which I'm trying to convert into a Blazor Server app. The issue that I'm running into is with the url routing. I'm trying to do something like this within my razor page

@Page "/{param}-items-for-sale.html"

blazor doesn't like this in .NET 7, Does .NET 8 support doing something like this?

Is there a way for me to route urls like this in my blazor app as I have many many pages which have already been indexed within the Search Engines and it would become a big issue if I had to change the format of the urls globally.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Write your own : https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components/Routing/Router.cs,7796d17e9548652a

Comment: seems like something like this will work with .NET 8

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using JavaScript to re-route:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@page "/"
@page "/{param}"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? param { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (param != null)
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("window.location.replace", $"{NavigationManager.BaseUri}{param}-items-for-sale.html");
    }
}
```